# How to disprove this fallacy that derivatives of $x^2$ and $x+x+x+\dots\quad(x\text{ times})$ are not same.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the flaw in this argument of a proof that 1=2? (Derivative of repeated addition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-argument-of-a-proof-that-1-2-derivative-of-repeated)

\begin{align*}
x^2 &= \underbrace{x + x + x + \dots + x}_{x \text{ times}}, \\
\therefore \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x^2)
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (\underbrace{x + x + x + \dots + x}_{x \text{ times}}) \\
&= \underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + \dots + 1}_{x \text{ times}} \\
&= x.
\end{align*}

But we know that
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x^2) = 2x. $$

So what is the problem?

My take is that
we cannot differentiate both sides because $\underbrace{{x+x+x+\cdots+x}}_{x \text{  times}}$ is not fixed and thus $1$ is not equal to $2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ times?

Comment: Adding x, x times
x+x+x+x....(x times x)

Comment: Worth reading. (http://www.maa.org/devlin/devlin_0708_08.html)

Comment: Note that the terms will be finite for any finite value of $x$

Comment: $x^2 = \lfloor x\rfloor x + (x-\lfloor x\rfloor)x$.  The first part, $\lfloor x\rfloor x$, is roughly like adding $x$ "$x$ times" while still adding an integer number of $x$s.  The derivative of $\lfloor x\rfloor x$ is $\lfloor x\rfloor$ where it is defined.

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples/39950#39950) too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Simply** because "$x \text{ times}$" is also a "function" of $x$. One mistake is not considering that in the derivation.

Comment: Besides, it's also not clear what it means to add a number to itself a non-integer number of times.  That interpretation of multiplication breaks down when you move beyond integers to fractions.

Comment: @Neal True. I'm thinking about it from the differentiation perspective.

Comment: I'm sure that Neal is also thinking about it from a differentiation perspective.  You can't take the derivative of a function with no definition, or that is defined only at the integers, in the context of calculus on the real line.

Answer (score 8):

You say "$x\text{ times}$".  The number of "times" you add it up---the number of terms in the sum---keeps changing as $x$ changes.  An what if $x=1.6701$?  How do you add up $x$ $1.6701$ times?

Comment: The arrangement of math equations in the question is very ugly. Help to edit it, such as $\underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{x\textrm{ times}}$ instead of the one in the question, and displaymath is not necessary. His $dy/dx$ can be arranged with inline math.

Comment: Concerning defining repeated addition for the reals, was your question for the OP's author's consideration? I think the problem is not with defining such addition, but with using the definition for $x^2$ that has been used in the OP.