# Funny Proof of $2=1$

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

We know $x.x=x^2$(Consider $x\ne 0$)

$x.x$ is adding $x$ $x$ times.
So we have

$x+x+\dots+x$($x$ times $x$ is added)=$x^2$......(1)

Differentiating both sides of (1) we get,

$1+1+\dots+1$(x times)=$2.x$

$\Rightarrow x=2x$

$1=2$ Proved.

Find out the mistake in this proof.

Comment: How does something occur $x$ times if $x\notin\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Also [How to disprove this fallacy that derivatives of $x^2$ and $x+x+x+⋯$ (x times) are not same](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164444/how-to-disprove-this-fallacy-that-derivatives-of-x2-and-xxx-cdots-x-tex)

Comment: You forgot the chain rule; you need to account for the derivative of the operation "... (x times)" (which, of course, doesn't exist since it's restricted to $x$ being an integer)

Comment: there is one evident mistake: x times is valid when x is integer. when it is integer differentiation is not valid.

Comment: The same reasoning shows that differentiating $x^2=\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{x^2\text{ times}}$ we get $0$.