# What is wrong in calculation of the derivative by this method?

Tags: derivatives

$$ y = x^2 $$
$$   y = \underbrace{x+ x+\cdots +x}_{x\text{ times}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\underbrace{1+ 1+\cdots +1}_{x\text{ times}} $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x$$

But the real answer is obviously $2x$. I know that I am making some kind of huge mistake but just can't find out where.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164444/how-to-disprove-this-fallacy-that-derivatives-of-x2-and-xxx-cdots-x-tex

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $x^2$ is not the derivative of the expression $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x x$, because the number of terms of the expression also depend on $x$. Let's look at your logic. You are saying that:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (x^2) = \frac{d}{dx} (\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{d}{dx} x  = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x 1 = x
$$
Which is wrong because the sum depends on $x$. Taking it out would be treating it like a constant, which it is not, because it depends on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

What if $x=\frac12$? Your representation fails.

In addition, you have completely disregarded the variable as an upper limit of the sum when differentiating.

So your formula is incorrect.

There may be a better formula that takes these things into account.