# What is wrong with my proof that $\int 2x dx= 2x^2$ by writing $2x=\underbrace{2+2+\cdots+2}_{x\;\text{times}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I know $\int 2x \,dx = x^2 + C$ (by the power rule) but why does the following proof not give the same answer?

\begin{align*}
\int 2x \,dx &= \int \underbrace{(2 + 2 + 2 + \dots + 2)}_{x \text{ times}} \, dx \\
             &= \underbrace{\int{2} \, dx + \int{2} \, dx + \dots \ + \int{2}_ \, dx}_{x \text{ times}}\\
             &= 2x + 2x + \dots + 2x + C \\
&= 2x \times x + C \\
&= 2x^2 + C
\end{align*}

(And I have the same question for this false proof that $\int{2^x} \, dx = 2^{x}x+ C$)

\begin{align*}
\int{2^x} \,dx &= \int \underbrace{(2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot 2)}_{x \text{ times}} \cdot 1 \, dx \\
             &= 2 \cdot \int \underbrace{(2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot 2)}_{(x-1) \text{ times}} \cdot 1 \, dx && (\text{Constant Multipule Rule})\\
             &= 2^2 \cdot \int \underbrace{(2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot 2)}_{(x-2) \text{ times}} \cdot 1 \, dx && (\text{Constant Multipule Rule})\\
             &= 2^x \cdot \int{1} \, dx \\
&= 2^{x}x+ C \\
\end{align*}

I suspect that it has something to do with not being able to:

1. Change integral of sums to sums of integrals for an arbitrary $x$, and
2. Remove a constant out of an integral if there are variable numbers of those constants.

But I'm not sure why these do not hold. If this is the reason, is there a theorem stating it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $x$ is a variable. You can't take it out of the integral. If you do want to convert an integral into a sum: this can be dome, but you have to be more careful.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164444 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096

Comment: @sloth FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bd(x%5E2)%7D%7Bdx%7D%3Dx%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aerror&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Spot the error in calculus](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1887198p12862895) which deals with basically the same question as the $2$nd link of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164444/602049 in Gary's comment above.

Comment: How would you use your approach to compute $\int x^{1.5}dx$, or $\int 1.5^xdx$?

Comment: Something more general...from algebra. I do not think there is a definition of adding something $s$ times,  where $s$ is not a naturall number.

Comment: Reviewers: this Question does *not* duplicate any of the above 3 linked suggestions because, cast as an integration question, it requires an answer that is not merely incidentally different from what the other 3 questions require. I know because I tried answering those instead and just leaving a pointer here, but wasn't able to shoehorn it.

Comment: Is $x$ integer-only? If $x$ is integer-only then what is $\int f(x)\, dx$?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096/442 for a similar error explained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first integral is wrong because $x\in\mathbb{R}$ need not be a natural number. So the multiplication cannot be split as you did. Similar reasoning applies to the second case, that is to say, since $x$ need not be a natural number, the interpretation for $2^{x}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The above comments and answer point out that you can't take a variable out of an integral, and that $x$ is not a natural number, but in fact, in the given examples, the error could be more fundamental.

Let $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=2^x.$ Giving benefit of the doubt that the author indeed meant to work in $\mathbb Z,$ that is, that
$$\int 2x \,\mathrm dx=\int f,\\
\int 2^x \,\mathrm dx=\int g,$$ then both integrals immediately equal $0,$ since the domain of integration in each case is a set of isolated points.

If the intention, however, was for *interval* integration domains, then it is of course invalid to assert that $2x=\underbrace{(2 + 2 + 2 + \dots + 2)}_{x \text{ times}}.$

Answer (score 0):

An integral might run from $x=0$ to $x=X$.

In $\int2xdx$, the function is increasing as you go along.  So the first $2$ is there all the way as x goes from 1 to X, but the second $2$ doesn't start until x is 2, and the final $2$ doesn't appear until x has already reached X.
In $\int2dx+\int2dx+...$, all the $2$s are there all the way as x goes from 0 to X.