# Another $1=2$ proof

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, fake-proofs

So a friend shows me this :

$x^4= x^2+x^2+ \cdots +x^2 $ ( i.e.  $x^2$ added $x^2$ times)

Now take the derivative of both side;

$4x^3 = 2x + 2x + \cdots + 2x $;

So $4x^3 = 2x^3  \cdots $(1)

And so dividing by $x^3$ gives  $2=1  \cdots $(2).

I know we can't divide by 0 so that makes (2) false, but to show that (1) is false too ?

Comment: The derivative on the RHS is incorrect. The number of $x^2$'s is dependent on $x$, so you would have to factor this into the derivative. Namely $x^2 + \cdots + x^2 = (x^2)(x^2) = (2x)(x^2) + (x^2)(2x) = 4x^3$.

Comment: Essentially, one side is treated like a constant while the other is treated like a function when the derivative is taken.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-proof-that-1-2-derivative-of-repeated-addition?rq=1 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First of all, the statement

> $x^2$ added $x^2$ times

makes sense only if $x^2$ is a positive integer. Else if $x^2$ is not a positive integer, then the statement is meaningless.

2. Moreover, from $(1)$, we have that $4x^3=2x^3 \Rightarrow 4x^3-2x^3=0 \Rightarrow 2x^3=0 \Rightarrow x^3=0$

And hence division by $x^3$ in the next step is meaningless.

Comment: But $x^3=0$ for all $x$ lets you substitute $x=1$ :) (Assuming the previous steps.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, but I couldn't get you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can only do the first step if $x^2$ is an positive integer.  So since it doesn't hold for all $x$ you can't take the derivative of both sides like that.  It doesn't even make sense to talk about "$x^2$ times" if $x^2$ is not a natural number. To take the derivative of both sides you'd need equality in an entire interval.