# Proof by derivative that 2=1

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

$$x^2=x + x + \cdots + x$$
Where x is repeated on the right hand side x times.

Take the derivative of both sides:
$$2x=1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$$
$$2x = x$$
$$2 = 1$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The right hand side sum's number of terms also depends on $x$ so you cannot just differentiate term by term like this!

Comment: What does $x+x+x+\cdots+x$ mean when $x=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: The higher-rated question, I guess, is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-proof-that-1-2-derivative-of-repeated-addition?rq=1

Comment: First off, the original equation is $x^2=x\cdot x$ so $x=0$. So then an equivalent way of expressing the fallacy that @SEWillB pointed out is that $(x\cdot x)'=2x\neq x$. This first fallacy is that $x$ is a variable, not a constant so it can't be treated as such. But that's not even the only fallacy, you've also got the fact that if $2x=x$ (and $x=0$) then division by $x$ is undefined. It's an easy mistake to make since it's not immediately apparent that you can't always divide through by $x$ but that last step *should* have been solved as $2x=x\Rightarrow 2x-x=0 \Rightarrow x=0$