# Derivatives and Counting question asked in an interview

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The below is a question that had been asked to one of my friends in an interview for admission into a premier management institute of India, the Indian Institute of Management.

Consider x^2. Now consider a series addition of x, x times as in x+x+x+x+....... x times.

Now we can see both x^2 and x+x+x+x+....... x times are same.

Now if we differentiate x^2 with respect to x, we get 2x.
And if we differentiate x+x+x+x+....... x times with respect to x, we get 1+1+1+1+..... x times, which equals x.

So why is this difference ?

Also when we look at x+x+x+x+....... x times as x × x, and then if we differentiate this wrt x using the product differentiation rule, we do get 2x as the derivative.

So why this paradox. This was asked in the interview. What could be the answer to this inconsistency?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-proof-that-1-2-derivative-of-repeated-addition).

Comment: How do you add $1.5$ to itself $1,5$ times?

Comment: $(x + x + x \cdots)$ $x$ times is $(x \cdot x)$ and by the product rule $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x \cdot x)$ gives us $x'x + x'x = 2x$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is $1+1+1...$ ($x$ times) is not the correct derivative of $x+x+x...$ ($x$ times)

This is because the NUMBER OF TIMES x is added to itself must also be differentiated.

In fact, as the slight increase in the x corresponds to a slight increase in the number of times $x$ is multiplied, which does not make sense with this analogy