# set theory: $A = \{3r+5s+8t \mid r,s,t \in\mathbb N, r = s + t\}$ and $C = \{n \in\mathbb N\mid 0 \le  \le 12\}$. Find $A\cap C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone kindly explain this question to me, I am not sure how to do this.

My approach: Since for Set $A = (r = S + T)$

$A = \{ 8s + 11t\mid s,t \in\mathbb N\}$

$C = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$

based on the interception of these two sets, $A$ must be $0 \le 8s + 11t \le 12$

Is my approach correct, from here I calculate set $A$ elements to be $\{0,8,11\}$

Comment: Are you treating $0$ as a natural number?  Also, in your definition of $C$, you wrote $nn$ where I think you meant $n$.

Comment: my apologies, i meant n only.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. But I think in your post you mean $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,...\}$. In that case there is a better notation. Use $\mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$ instead.

Comment: He can use $\Bbb N$, this isn't the Middle Ages: it's just the internet.

Comment: Yep I explained the issue there https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3240942/399263