# Why can't we take derivative when the number of terms depends on $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1097/818920).

> You cannot take the derivative of $\underbrace{x + x + x + \dots + x}_{\text{repeated $x$ times}}$ with respect to $x$ one term at a time because the number of terms depends on $x$.

In this case, why can't we take derivative one term at a time when the number of terms depends on $x$?

Comment: This supposes $x$ can only be a natural number. What would a derivative mean in this context?

Comment: @Bernard It can be made continuous. Read the entire answer.

Comment: Sure, but ‘repeated $\lfloor x\rfloor$ times’ is not the same as ‘repeated $x$ times’.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't understand.

Comment: You wrote the second phrasing, which does not mean the same as the first.

Comment: Not clear what you mean when you say $x$ times for non natural $x$. if you mean $(x[x])'=[x]$ where that's defined, that would be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can it is by the chain rule : $$\underbrace{(1+1+\cdots+1)}_{x \text{ times}}+\underbrace{(x+x+\cdots+x)}_{1\text{ times}}=x+x=2x$$

---

More seriously, derivating requires a 'continuous' variable, it makes no sense for integers. I talk about integers because the underbrace $\underbrace{\hphantom{---}}_{n\text{ times}}$ implicitely supposes $n$ is an integer.

However the continuous version of the sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)$ is the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^x f(t)\mathop{dt}$

And by the fundamental theorem of calculs this integral has derivative $f(x)$, so we can somehow give a (very twisted I admit) meaning to the derivative of the underbrace with an $x$ variable.

See Mickael E2's answer in the link you provided yourself https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3643749/39926

Comment: I understood your answer but not the point of your answer. Please explain.

Comment: comment: do not take this too seriously...