# Is the distributive law of multiplication valid when the number of terms are variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, arithmetic-functions

In brief the distributive law for natural numbers states that:

Let $a$,$b$,$c$ naturals then $a \cdot (b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c$

And this could be generalized by induction:

Let $a, a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$ naturals then $a\cdot (a_1 + a_2 + \ldots +a_n) = a \cdot a_1 + a\cdot a_2 + \ldots +a\cdot a_n$

Those are valid propierties  with other objects, for example, integers, real numbers, complex numbers, matrices, functions, etc.  because their definition is based on this.

But what happens when $n$ is not a fixed natural but a variable? I'm interested in this because I want to know if the following is valid:

Let $N$ be a natural number, then:
$$ N = \overbrace{1+1+\ldots +1}^{N- times}$$ and multiplying by N on the left in both sides of the equality we get $$ N\cdot N = N \cdot(\overbrace{1+1+\ldots +1}^{N- times}) $$ now the left hand side becomes $N^2$ and until this point I agree this is valid. But I'm not sure that $N \cdot(\overbrace{1+1+\ldots +1}^{N- times}) = \overbrace{N + N + \ldots + N}^{N- times}$ becasue this will bring a contradiction if we think this as a function. $$N^2 = \overbrace{N + N + \ldots + N}^{N- times}$$ and derive both side with respect to N $$ \frac{d}{dN}(N^2) = \frac{d}{dN}\left((\overbrace{N + N + \ldots + N}^{N- times})\right) \\
2N = \overbrace{1 + 1 + \ldots + 1}^{N-times} = N$$

And clearly the function $N$ is not equal to the function $2N$, hence a contradiction

I'm sure that the distributive law is failing with the derivative operator, but I'm not sure with the multiplication operator.

Being more specific:
if $c$ is a constant and $v$ a variable is the following assertion valid?
$$\overbrace{ c + c +c \ldots +c }^{v -\text{times}} =^{?} c \cdot(\overbrace{1+1+\cdot+1}^{ v-\text{times}}) $$

### EDIT

Because some users identified this as a possible duplicate of: [Where is the flaw in this "proof" that 1=2? (Derivative of repeated addition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-proof-that-1-2-derivative-of-repeated-addition). I want to add more information to explain why that does not answer my question.

My current question is not about the derivative or why the proof fails, that is well answered there. My query is, as stated in the title, about the validity of distributive law when the amount of terms are **variables**.  Another example:

Let  $n$ be a constant  thus $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k = 2^0+2^1+...+2^n$$
(the upper n-times brace is obviated here) but if $n$ is a variable we could tend to infinity but this may cause trouble when trying to apply the basic arithmetic law:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^k = 2^0+2^1+2^2+... \\
 = 1 + 2 \cdot (2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2+ \ldots ) \text{(Distributive law when $n$ variable tend to infinity)} \\
= 1 + 2 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k   $$
But this is absurd because if the identity holds then:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^k = -1$$
The sum of only positive numbers being a negative number. So we cannot apply freely the basic properties of numbers when they are variable because that variable may behave like infinity.

### EDIT 2

Well, I will be the most specific I could reach here and if this doesn't have an answer I give up.

Let $a$ be a number and $\{a_j\}_{ j\in J}$  an indexed collection of numbers. Then $$ a \cdot \sum_{j\in J}a_j = \sum_{j\in J}a\cdot a_j$$ if $J$ is finite. That's for sure, we begin with the (I think axiom) distributive law for naturals.

But what if J is not finite. ie. be infinity but numerable or infinity but not numerable. This property still holds?  If so why? because the generalization of induction uses a set not finite but numerable. So it may not work when the set of index is not finite and not numerable.

Comment: Yes, $\overbrace{c+c+c+\dots+c}^{v-\text{times}}=c\cdot (\overbrace{1+1+1+\cdots+1}^{v-\text{times}}$.  Your error is in attempting to derive the summation term by term noting that the terms in the summation depend on $N$ but having ignored that the number of terms *also* depends on $N$.

Comment: Yes, I notice that in the derivative, but I was not sure about the identity $\overbrace{ c + c +c \ldots +c }^{v -\text{times}} =^{?} c \cdot(\overbrace{1+1+\cdot+1}^{ v-\text{times}}) $ in natural numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz Well that was of great help and I asked this question due my work on that tricky "proof", I needed to know where the contradiction begins.

Comment: Why should you doubt that?  You even began your post saying that you believed and had supposedly proven by induction that $a\cdot (a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots+a_n) = a\cdot a_1+a\cdot a_2+\cdots + a\cdot a_n$.  All that varies between this and the sum of $v$ copies of $c$ is by setting $n=v$, $a=c$ and $a_i=1$ for all $i$ and evaluating $c\cdot 1$ as $c$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I doubt because the behavior of the study object in consideration. Of course when $n$ is a fixed number ( a constant in term of functions) the distributive law hold. But when a variable behavior is consider and $n$ is not a single number but many as once I didn't how to manage that. I mean if $n$ is a variable what stop it from behave like infinity? and in that case the arithmetic law ( associativity, commutativity, distributive)  does not necessarily hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any finite number of terms, the distributive law holds by an inductive argument.
It holds even if you have not decided how many terms are in the sum,
as long as you are sure you have an integer number of terms.

The inductive argument that works for sums with finitely many terms does not directly apply to infinite series, because there is no integer that tells the number of terms in the series.
Still, multiplication distributes over all the partial sums of the series, so you can prove that if

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = L, $$

where $L$ is a real number, and if $b$ is a real number, that

$$  \sum_{k=1}^\infty b a_k =
b \sum_{k=1}^\infty  a_k = b L. $$

You cannot apply this result when the sum does not converge.
It is not true in that case.
It does not even make sense; multiplication is about multiplying **numbers**, not numbers and whatever quantity a divergent series represents.

Your examples show some of the nonsensical results that occur if you incorrectly assume that you can multiply a divergent sum by a number and manipulate the result as if it were a number.

Comment: "[Distributive propierty] holds even if you have not decided how many terms are in the sum, as long as you are sure you have an integer number of terms." That's what I mean by **variable** numbers of terms.  This answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to express the same idea without using the word "variable". I agree it is the same thing you described.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}N}\left( \overbrace{N+N+\cdots+N}^{\text{$N$-times}} \right) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left( \overbrace{(N+h)+(N+h)+\cdots+(N+h)}^{\text{$(N+h)$-times}} \right) - \left( \overbrace{N+N+\cdots+N}^{\text{$N$-times}} \right)}{h}$$

Why are you ignoring the "${}+h$" in the overbrace?

Comment: I understand your point, but  besides that calculates the correct derivative, I want to know about the distributive property.  I'm working in and EDIT so I hope I will become more clear.

Comment: @JoséMarín : You claim that variable arity distribution of mulitplication over addition is false by using a flawed computation of the derivative.  When that flaw is corrected, you have no objection.  With no objection, the question is answered.

Comment: I see. As I understand, this proves that $N \cdot(\overbrace{1+1+\ldots +1}^{N- times})$ and $ \overbrace{N + N + \ldots + N}^{N- times}$ have the same derivative but this doesn't mean they are the same function.

Comment: @JoséMarín : The claim that those two expressions define the same function is from your argument.  Since that claim is correct, I don't comment on it.